# How do I create an instance of RecordN manually in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, testing, jooq

I am writing some tests for a script that imports data into a database. The unit tests for the script look more or less like

```
doAnImport(fileName, databaseToImportInto)
Result<Record2<String, Integer>> results 
    = databaseToImportInto.select(aStringField, anIntegerField)
                          .from(oneTable)
                          .join(anotherTable).on(someField.eq(someOtherField)
                          .fetch();
```

What I would like to do now is Junit assertions something like

```
assertEquals(10, results.getSize());
assertTrue(results.contains(new Record2<String, Integer>(expectedString1, expectedInteger1);
...
assertTrue(results.contains(new Record2<String, Integer>(expectedString10, expectedInteger10);
```

because I don't want to assume any particular ordering in the results. My problem is that Record2 is an interface, and RecordImpl is not publicly visible.

The other options I can see (making the test query into a view and generating classes for it so that there's an XXXRecord implementation) is not really available to me - there's a large and growing of these queries, and I don't want to tie my database schema to the peculiarities of my test cases.

I guess I could create my own subclass of RecordImpl, but that seems like a lot of work, so I'm guessing given the elegance of the rest of the library (if you haven't tried it, you really should), that this is not the "right thing".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. I found the answer when looking at other documentation.

```
DSL.row()
```

will return an implementation of RowN, and then you can use that to compare with results, by calling

```
Record.valuesRow()
```

on the values in the results.

For the record, my utility function for testing now looks like this

```
public static void looksLike(boolean matchSize, Result<?> results, Row ... theseRows)
{
    if (matchSize)
    {
        assertEquals(results.size(), theseRows.length);
    }

    List<Row> resultsRows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    for (Record r : results)
    {
        resultsRows.add(r.valuesRow());
    }

    for (Row r : theseRows)
    {
        assertTrue(r.toString() + " missing from " + results, resultsRows.contains(r));
    }
}
```

As I said I thought in the question, there was indeed an easy way to do what I wanted. Another tick in the JOOQ box.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can see to achieve this would be:

```
assertEquals(new HashSet<>(result1), new HashSet<>(result2));
```

This would compare two `Result` objects, ignoring the record order. And this is how you create ad-hoc records:

```
Record record = DSL.using(...).newRecord(result1.fields());
```

But there's probably room for improved API, indeed.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. That's simpler than what I came up with  :)

Comment: Actually, on further consideration,  I'm not sure that it is simpler. Your approach using DSL.newRecord() requires a field-by-field call to setValue, whereas the DSL.row() approach allows DSL.row("val1", 10, fasle, 10.6) so it's probably a simpler approach at the test-site, where these values are being created. Since that's the most frequent thing (I only have to write looks-like once, but I call it a large and growing number of times) I think my approach is simpler. But I didn't realise I could HashSet the results - that's a cool trick.

Comment: @BurleighBear: That's what I meant by *"But there's probably room for improved API"*. There could be `Row.record()` or something like that...